# How do you handle firewall rules from multiple sources that each need dozens of ports opened?

Tags: networking, firewall, azure, azure-networking

We have multiple locations that all need to reach the same Azure vnet. I have a network security group for our private DMZ that needs to allow ports 22, 80, 443, 445, 3306, 3389, 8080, 8443, 8843, 8880, and several others.

I'm finding that the 4096 rule limit in Azure is filling up fast.

Since the source IP will always be our network, what are the implications of just allowing ALL from each source and reducing the 35-40 rules per site down to just 1 each. Our Linux hosts use iptables as well and have a more indepth policy that limits the port with source IP.

Comment: Were you creating a unique rule for each unique ip address from each source network? If so then yes, I'd set up a single rule for each source network that encompasses the entire source network.

Comment: Yes, so one source IP would have 35 rules, one for each port basically. It got overwhelming to manage and was nearing the 4096 rule limit per NSG.

Answer (score 1):

Azure NSG support `Source IP address range`+`Destination port range`.

[image]

However, for now, IP address ranges only support one range, if you have multiple IP address ranges, you need create multiple NSG rules. So, if possible, I suggest you could merge IP address segment, it will reduce your NSG rules.

Comment: Not really the answer to my question since I've been using CIDR and Port Ranges already. It's just with having so many ports that aren't grouped together, my list got very long. I ended up removing everything and just using * for the Port range.

Comment: @mavdog71x Yes, you could  do this. But people could access some port that they don't have the permissions. If you trust you source people, of course, you could do this.

Comment: @mavdog71x Could you merge your IP address segment?